# Double standards on recognizing expression as functional

Tags: terminology, calculus-of-variations

The [Calculus of Variations](http://ice.as.arizona.edu/~dpsaltis/Phys422/chapter5.pdf) starts with a definition of functional

> Such an expression, the argument of which is a function, is called a
>   functional.

Particularly, they say that $J = \int_a^b{y(x)dx}$ is a functional. Yet, when $y$ is expanded with another variable, $\alpha$, they say that $J(\alpha) = \int_a^b{y(x,\alpha)dx} (5.5)$ is not a functional "because it is a function of parameter $\alpha$"! So, $J$ which has no arguments is considered as functional but $\int_a^b{y(x,\alpha)dx}$, which has function $y$ as its argument is not considered a functional. Why? Is it because name of parameter $\alpha$? In my opinion, both J do the same thing - compute the length of the path. I do not see how adding a free variable $\alpha$ to choose the path undoes this fact.

Comment: I don't find this to be adequate enough for a full answer but this might help: [Functionals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_(mathematics)). In general I've understood a functional to be a mapping from some vector space (i.e. banach space, hilbert space, etc.) to, in general, some field, but often for the work I've done, specifically to the reals.

Comment: Note that $J$ assigns to any function $y(x)$ a real number, that is, it is a function that assigns to a function a value. However, $J(\alpha)$ assigns a real number to a real number. So it can be considered a function. The main difference is that, in $J,$ $y$ can be any function (in a certain set of functions) and, in $J(\alpha),$ $y$ must be considered a given function.

Comment: @ManuelFdzLpz I guessed that. Yet, I do not see where they instantiate $y$. They split it into two components, but it is not concrete since they explicitly highlight that the second component is _arbitrary_. Do you say that f is arbitrary function but it becomes concrete if I say that f = 1 + arbitary function g?

Comment: Sorry because I didn't see the reference you quote. But the answer is the same. Note that it is said "Given that we have fixed the solution $y_0(x)$ ant the  arbitrary function $n(x)$" (so, $y_0$ and $n$ are fixed and it only changes $\alpha$). So, if you consider a particular $y,$ say $y(x,\alpha)=(x-\alpha)^2,$ then $J(\alpha)$ is just a function.

Comment: @ManuelFdzLpz Wait. Double standards again. Why do you say that arbitrary $n$ is fixed but arbitrary $y$ is not?

Comment: No, I should say $y_0.$ Both of them fixed functions.

Comment: @ManuelFdzLpz Why $y_0(x) + \alpha n(x)$ is fixed? n(x) is arbitrary. You do not know what is result when you apply x. Why arbitrary y(x) is fixed but arbitrary n(x) is not? What does "fixed" mean?

Comment: $n$ is arbitrary but fixed (well, twice differentiable and with some boundary conditions). That is, you don't know $n,$ but you have to think of it is a fixed function. You only allow to change $\alpha.$ These are the assumptions made in $5.5$.

Comment: In the end, once you have achieve an integral equality, only using dependence on $\alpha,$ which is satisfied for any $n$ (because it was arbitrary) you can get that the integrand vanishes.